# How to set a proxy for terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, proxy, tor

I am looking to set a proxy for terminal. What I need is I want to send all terminal communications to the internet through a proxy, say tor.

I tried to set a system wide proxy set up. But Terminal doesn't obey the system wide proxy configuration.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You mean ssh or telnet or ... ? Please explain us "terminal communications". You can telnet to some host via proxy or ftp them, but communication from minicom you can not send via net ... except like log file ....

Comment: Is it possible to set a proxy for all network related activities done over the terminal? Instead of setting proxy for wget,curl and others separately. I am looking for such a solution.

Comment: Yes, but wget usually work on port 80 or 443, ssh on port 22, telnet on 23, ftp on 20 and 21 ... You can use [simpleproxy](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/simpleproxy.1.html) or [tinyproxy](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/tinyproxy.8.html)

Comment: How to set this proxy for terminal? Do I explicitly set it for different apps running on terminal or can I set it in terminal such a way that all the commands I run in terminal go through this proxy?

Comment: ubuntu terminal needs http proxy, when you use SOCKS5 proxy, like shadowsocks, you can use `proxychains` to bridge SOCKS5 to http proxy. Check this https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Using-Shadowsocks-with-Command-Line-Tools

Comment: you can `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/*yourarch*/torsocks/libtorsocks.so`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Terminal is not net application. Maybe is better to say, in your case, terminal is container for net application like `ssh`, `telnet`, `lftp`, `wget`, `lynx` ...

Edit your:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
```

Enter the details in this format.

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ 
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
export telnet_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

This is for when using `wget`, `ftp`, `lftp`, `telnet` in terminal

`ssh` has no native `SOCKS` client support, you need to use a `ProxyCommand` for that, for instance with `socat`:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - SOCKS4A:myproxy:%h:%p,socksuser=nobody' user@host
```

Or use things like `tsocks` to transparently use `SOCKS` for `TCP` traffic.

For `SOCKS5` with socat 2:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - "SOCKS5:%h:%p|tcp:myproxy:1080"' user@host
```

For HTTP Proxy CONNECT method with socat 2:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - "PROXY:%h:%p|tcp:myproxy:80"' user@host
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the proxy.sh file should be made executable.

Answer (score 79):

export the below variables in terminal

```
export http_proxy='http://proxyServerSddress:proxyPort'    
export https_proxy='https://proxyServerSddress:proxyPort'
```

and use the following commands to disable proxy

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Comment: +1 for unset instruction :)

Answer (score 3):

using torsocks this can be accomplished like so:

```
ultralazer@askubuntu:~$ torsocks --shell
New torified shell coming right up...

ultralazer@askubuntu:~$ curl icanhazip.com
185.220.100.242 (tor ip)
```

man page:

```
ultralazer@askubuntu:~$ torsocks --help
ultralazer@askubuntu:~$ man torsocks
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was either missing enclosing inverted comma on both sides.
putting `"http//.."` was wrong and not putting anything such as `http//...` was wrong too. What worked was ..when I used single inverted commas on both sides.

`export http_proxy='http://username:password@proxyhost:port/' 
export https_proxy='https://username:password@proxyhost:port/'
export ftp_proxy='http://username:password@proxyhost:port/'`

Remember these three are 3 commands to be run separately three times.

Answer (score 1):

I set export variables

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ 
export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyhost:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

in ~/.bashrc and /etc/enviroment

Answer (score 1):

From my research this was the only thing that worked for me:

Install ProxyChains:

```
sudo apt-get install proxychains
```

Edit the conf file to use your proxy:

```
sudo vi /etc/proxychains.conf
```

Check the last line and edit it.
Then just run:

```
proxychains ssh/curl/wget
```

or whatever command you want to go through the proxy.

[This is someone else answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71481/how-to-use-socks-proxy-for-commands-in-terminal-such-as-youtube-dl)